# Postgres loading datatable to PgAdmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am new to Postgres and i am trying to learn from an online tutorial. One of the first thing is to load the data, as follows:

> Finally, run `psql -U <username> -f clubdata.sql -d postgres -x -q` to
>   create the 'exercises' database, the Postgres 'pgexercises' user, the
>   tables, and to load the data in. Note that you may find that the sort
>   order of your results differs from those shown on the web site:

I am using pdAdmin4 and opened the SQL shell. However I wasn't able to load this database. First of all, how can i figure out what is my current `username`?

Secondly, I have never worked with command line before and am quite unsure how to do this. Could someone break this down step-by-step?

Comment: Clearly "someonee" is writing on a macbook :D

Answer (score 0):

You can run "psql -h" for more help. You never have a current username as such, you have to specify it but start with "-U postgres" and ask again if that doesn't work.
Your sql file to load will need the folder path or you could try the cmd prompt and change to the folder where your clubdata file is. Your command line assumes there is already a database named postgres which there probably is. Try again;

psql -U postgres -f clubdata.sql -d postgres -x -q

Answer (score 0):

The command `psql` is for the command line client. You need to run this in a terminal.

I wrestled with this input myself, despite a little CLI experience with psql. It may help to remove the `-q` flag in the end to make the output non-quiet, then you see what's going on.

Lastly, beware that the import creates a schema, so you need to read up on schemas. See this related question for a bit more background: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264398/cant-find-any-tables-after-psql-dump-import-from-pgexercises-com